# What date format is Date().toDateString() in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

In [W3School's page for toDateString() function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_todatestring.asp) , it says when you call toDateString() it will give something like `Mon Jan 12 2015`. It makes me wonder which date format `toDateString()` conforms to?

Is it "EEE MMM dd YYYY" or "EEE MMM d YYYY"?

Comment: Try it out in your browser's console. For me, it's the former (leading zeros) in Chrome on Windows 8.1. i.e.: `(new Date(2015, 1, 9)).toDateString()` => "Mon Feb 09 2015".

Comment: You'll get a more consistent result from `toISOString()`, but note that it is not present in IE through version 8.

Answer (score 4):

From the ECMAScript 5.1 spec:

> **[15.9.5.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.3) Date.prototype.toDateString ( )**
>
> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are
>   implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the “date”
>   portion of the Date in the current time zone in a convenient,
>   human-readable form.

Therefore, you can't assume any format, it's implementation-dependent.

Comment: In other words, you can't rely on it being in any particular format at all. `toDateString()` is convenient in some situations where precise control over the format doesn't matter, but most of the time, you need to do your own date formatting (or use something like https://github.com/samsonjs/strftime)

Comment: In my implementation, what format is toDateString() is irrelevant. I am solely interested in its date format for personal sake. However, its truly appreciated to point out that the format changes in different languages. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @oasisweng Implementation-dependent means that you can't expect different implementations (e.g. web browsers) to use the same format. For example, Firefox and Chrome could use different formats, or Firefox 33 and Firefox 34 could use different formats, or Firefox 34 could use different formats on different computers, or Firefox 34 could use a random format.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good link to Mozilla:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString

The format follows (when using moment.js): **'EEE MMM d YYYY'**

Comment: MDN is a public wiki for Mozilla browsers (in other words, it isn't a specification or standard and is almost exclusively for Mozilla browsers). The linked reference states only "*…human readable form in American English*", there is no definitive format. Firefox 34 doesn't conform to the above format anyway.